# REST API for configuration / configuring a service

Tags: web-services, rest, api-design

I have a service that captures data at 10 minute intervals and allows users to subscribe to receive that data, query for data, receive e-mails when their data changes, etc, all via a REST API.

I'd like to allow users to configure the service to use data that is captured at 1 hour intervals, but since this configuration effects the entire service not just one particular resource/feature, I'm not sure how best to capture this information via a REST API. Are there any approaches for capturing this sort of general service configuration information via a REST API? Are there precedents for this?

Comment: I really don't get it. What's the problem with the user setting the 'interval' attribute of some resource to either 1 hours or 10 minutes?

Comment: Because it's a global setting that applies to all resources. So setting it on each resource wouldn't really work.

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. Maybe you can edit your question and clarify it. Giving a few examples of how it is and how you imagine it could be might help.

Comment: Could you not design it as a query parameter `/endpoint/?interval=60` or if no parameter is specified, default it to 10?